# Compose a value from multiple select boxes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I have a model A with a some B. This attribute B can be composed of multiple values and is joined by a colon (:) when done so.

For example if the value of B is 1,2 and 3, the representation is 1:2:3.

This is done because all three values can come from different user choices. Now I know the database can be changed to handle this, however, the database is not in my control, so here is what I'm asking.

I have 3 selects in my form all with :B as their attribute, but the params hash only accepts the last one as passed in. Is there a way I can get all three values so I can form the correct representation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your form you can try this:

```
form_for A do |f|
  text_field_tag "b[]", "Item 1"
  text_field_tag "b[]", "Item 2"
  text_field_tag "b[]", "Item 3"
```

it will pass the value from the 3 fields

Comment: can't I use a select_tag instead?

Comment: i used an inspired solution. instead of b[], i just named them differently and that worked for my solution.